# Pagination with lot of records avoid limit offset

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

For example, i has big MySQL table (10kk records).
Table struct:

```
CREATE TABLE `contents` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  /* some fields hidden */
  `update_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', /* INDEX */
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`update_time` may be changed to current UNIX timestamp any time.
Select query:

```
SELECT ... FROM contents WHERE ... ORDER BY update_time DESC [LIMIT ...];
```

How to make pagination, avoid LIMIT OFFSET?
LIMIT OFFSET not useful for this query, because it's reading too much unneeded rows. For example, `SELECT ... FROM contents LIMIT 9000000, 100` will read ~9000100 rows.

Comment: As I know, you must set index for columns , then it makes your query faster.Beside that, when you use offset , Mysql will start from index and get data.

Comment: As from MySQL documentation: " With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)":

SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

Comment: But they will read 15 rows, not 10. So, at LIMIT 1000, 5 will be read 1005 rows, at LIMIT 10000000, 5 will be read 10000005 rows. I want avoid read unneeded data.